# I am unable to use strtok over a char

Tags: c, string, dynamic

I am unable to use strtok over char *a but on b its working.

Its working with malloc and array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DELIM ":"

int main()
{
    char *a = "xgdgsf: duh d";//unable to use strtok on it
    char *token=NULL;
    printf("%s",a);
    char *b = malloc(strlen(a) + 1);
    strcpy(b, a);//i can use strtko on it

    token=strtok(b,DELIM);
    printf("\n%s",token);
    token=strtok(a,DELIM);
    printf("\n%s",token);
    return 0;                                                                                        
 }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Describe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
char *a = "xgdgsf: duh d";
```

to

```
char *a = strdup("xgdgsf: duh d");
```

In C, string literals are read only. However, do remember that you need to `free` the pointer after calling `strdup`. Do it with `free(a)` when you are done with the string.

Comment: +1 and maybe not necessary for this question, but could be worth noting to free `a` later on due to `strdup`

Comment: @Trickzter I was considering it, but I don't think it's necessary at this stage.

Comment: It is never too soon to make people aware that they should close what they open and free what to allocate.

Answer (score 2):

You have passed `a` to `strtok` which is a string literal. You can't do that because `strtok` modifies the string.

If you had defined the array as

```
const char *a = "xgdgsf: duh d";
```

then the compiler would give you a warning.

The *second* call to `strtok` should be

```
token=strtok(NULL, DELIM);
```

to extract the *second* token from `b`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that `a` points to a *string literal*. `strtok` modifies its input (it overwrites the delimiters with a string terminator) and the behavior on attempting to modify a string literal is *undefined* - you may get a runtime error, the code may work as expected, or something else may happen.  String literals are *supposed* to be immutable, but it's not guaranteed that they'll be stored in read-only memory.

There are several ways to resolve this.  One is to declare `a` as an array and initialize it with the string:

```
char a[] = "xgdgsf: duh d";
```

Another is to dynamically allocate a buffer and copy the contents of the string to it:

```
char *a = malloc( strlen( "xgdgsf: duh d" ) + 1 );
if ( a )
  strcpy( a, "xgdgsf: duh d" );
```

If it's available on your system, you can use the non-standard function `strdup` to do the same thing:

```
char *a = strdup( "xgdgsf: duh d" );
```

When declaring a pointer to a string literal, it's usually a good idea to qualify it as `const`:

```
const char *a = "xgdgsf: duh d";
```

that way the compiler will yak at you if you try to modify (assign to) `*a` or `a[i]` or pass it to a function that expects a plain `char *` as an input.  That way mistakes like using `strtok` on a literal are caught at compile time, not runtime.